# Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect time value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM SESSIONS
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), SESSION_CREATED)) / 3600 >= 24
```

This give me 2 results

```
DELETE FROM SESSIONS
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), SESSION_CREATED)) / 3600 >= 24
```

And this give me: "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect time value"

SESSION_CREATED is TIMESTAMP Datatype

Actual data:

```
SESSION_ID      SESSION_CREATED
223133          2017-05-22 07:14:34
223134          2017-05-22 07:14:36
```

How can the select work but not the delete?

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: can you post your data

Comment: Add `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), SESSION_CREATED)) / 3600` to the first query's select list. Does the returned data make sense?

Comment: Is `now()` valid in `sql-server`?

Comment: @jarlh - it make sense

Comment: @Utsav - MySQL, my mistake

Comment: @jarlh - no triggers involved, plain SQL

Answer (score 20):

Why are you using such a complicated expression?  Why not just do:

```
DELETE FROM SESSIONS
    WHERE SESSION_CREATED < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

As for why your code might fail, it is using `timediff()` which is limited to the range of the time data type.  [And this is:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html)

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

Because you are using `NOW()`, the values change from one iteration to the next.  You just happened to run the `SELECT` when the data wasn't too old and then the `DELETE` when it was.

Comment: It make sens but still... I get results every single day I run the select (never crashes) but in return every single day I run the delete, I bump into this error. It can't be a matter of time. Anyway, I'm gonna use your statement, Thank you.

Comment: You might want to use `SESSION_CREATED <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` @Vlad Florin

Comment: Yes, there are few solutions out there that work for the deletion I need. I was just wondering why this particular one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Example for Timediff using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` on MySQL:

To use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, define the unit (`SECOND`, `MINUTE`, `HOUR`...), the initial and end date (must be timestamp's datatype).

```sql
ROUND( TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, initial_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) / 24, 2 )
```